# BufferOverflowException while converting int to byte

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I have an `counter` which counts from 0 to 32767

At each step, I want to convert the `counter` (int) to an 2 byte array.

I've tried this, but I got a `BufferOverflowException`  exception:

```
byte[] bytearray = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putInt(counter).array();
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect? You try to put 4 bytes into a buffer which is 2 bytes long.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: changed max number to 32767

If I do that by shifting, the value 128 will be -128. But I need positiv bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is because an `int` takes 4 bytes in a buffer, regardless of the value.

[`ByteBuffer.putInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int)) is clear about both this and the exception:

> Writes four bytes containing the given int value, in the current byte order, into this buffer at the current position, and then increments the position by four.
>
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
> `BufferOverflowException` - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

To write two bytes, use `putShort` instead... and ideally change your `counter` variable to be a `short` as well, to make it clear what the range is expected to be.

Comment: It works by using short, but if the counter reaches 128, the converted byte will be -128 instead of 128

Comment: @Struct: It will be the appropriate set of bits - it's just that `byte` in Java is (unfortunately) signed. There *is* no `byte` value of 128. Whatever converts the two-byte value back into a `short` will get the right value out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to assume that the int is big endian. Well, this is Java so it will certainly be the case.

Second, your error is expected: an int is 4 bytes.

Since you want the two last bytes, you can do that without having to go through a byte buffer:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(final int counter)
{
    final byte[] ret = new byte[2];
    ret[0] = (byte) ((counter & 0xff00) >> 8);
    ret[1] = (byte) (counter & 0xff);
    return ret;
}
```

You could also use a `ByteBuffer`, of course:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(final int counter)
{
    // Integer.BYTES is there since Java 8
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES);
    buf.put(counter);
    final byte[] ret = new byte[2];
    // Skip the first two bytes, then put into the array
    buf.position(2);
    buf.put(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: it seems there are 2 typos in ByteBuffer example:
buf.put(counter) -> buf.putInt(counter);
buf.put(ret) -> buf.get(ret);

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Writes two bytes containing the given short value, in the
 current byte order, into this buffer at the current position, and then
 increments the position by two.

```
byte[] bytearray = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort((short)counter).array();
```